# ImportError: cannot import name 'cpp_household' from 'roboschool'

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

pls help me. I can not import lib

roboschool 1.0.49 
gym==0.15.4

input

```
import roboschool
```

output

```
D:\Users\gumin\anaconda3\python.exe D:/Users/gumin/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/roboschool/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/gumin/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/roboschool/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import roboschool
  File "c:\users\gumin\roboschool\roboschool\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from roboschool.gym_pendulums import RoboschoolInvertedPendulum
  File "c:\users\gumin\roboschool\roboschool\gym_pendulums.py", line 1, in <module>
    from roboschool.scene_abstract import SingleRobotEmptyScene
  File "c:\users\gumin\roboschool\roboschool\scene_abstract.py", line 12, in <module>
    from roboschool  import cpp_household   as cpp_household
ImportError: cannot import name 'cpp_household' from 'roboschool' (c:\users\gumin\roboschool\roboschool\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're on Windows. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/openai/roboschool/issues/170#issuecomment-511914098), roboschool doesn't work on Windows, unfortunately.